# Problema con $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, php7

Tengo el siguiente codigo para un formulario de inicio de sesion, desde una pagina anterior envio por metodo POST la variable `id_modulo` y la recupero en la pagina de inicio de sesion, pero si el usuario escribe mal la contraseña o el nombre de usuario el sistema se queda en la misma pagina ya que el action del formulario es `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. En este mismo formulario tengo un campo oculto para guardar el resultado de la variable `id_modulo`, pero sucede que al recargar la pagina por el motivo antes expuesto (usuario o contraseña mal) no puedo recuperar el valor de `id_modulo`, me da el error de:

> Notice: Undefined index: id_modulo in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\seguridad\cuestionario\loginp.php on line 67

Codigo de la pagina:

```
$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$id_modulo = $_POST['id_modulo'];
if ($id_modulo == "todos") {
  echo "<h3>CUESTIONARIO CON TODOS LOS MODULOS</h3>";
}else{

 $SQLModulo = "SELECT * FROM modulos WHERE id_modulo='$id_modulo'";
 $SQLconsultaModulo = $conexionmysqli->query($SQLModulo);
 $SQLconsultaModulo->data_seek(0);
 $row_nombreModulo = $SQLconsultaModulo->fetch_assoc();
 $nombreModulo ="".$row_nombreModulo['n_modulo']."";
 $SQLconsultaModulo->close(); // Liberar memoria usada por consulta.
  echo "<h3>$nombreModulo</h3>";
 }
```

```html
<form role="form" id="login" name="form_ingreso" method="post" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>">
                          <input type="text" name="id_modulo" id="id_modulo" value="<?php echo"$id_modulo"; ?>">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Usuario</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control field required" name="usuario" id="login_username" value="" placeholder="..." data-toggle="tooltip" title="Teclee su nombre de usuario" data-placement="bottom" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Contrase&ntilde;a</span>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control field required" name="contrasena"  value="" id="login_password" placeholder="..." data-toggle="tooltip" title="Teclee su contrase&ntilde;a" data-placement="bottom">
                                </div>
                                <p class="help-block"><em>Verifique que la tecla Block May&uacute;s (CAPS LOCK) no este activada.</em></p>
                                <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                            </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">ACCEDER</button>
                        </div>
                        <span class="pull-right"><a href="../" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">REGRESAR</a></span>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: Además del error al llamar a una variable que no existe, ¿Para qué estás seteando el valor del action? Es más sencillo usar `action=""`, que va a publicar en la misma página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que la página inicial (que no tiene fijado el módulo) muestra todos los módulos, entonces puedes comprobar si está seteada la superglobal `$_POST['id_modulo']` y en caso contrario asumir que es "todos".

```
$id_modulo = isset($_POST['id_modulo']) ? $_POST['id_modulo'] : 'todos';
```

El error que te da es porque intentas recuperar una llave que no está presente en `$_POST`, lo cual ocurrirá cuando no envíes el formulario sino que cargues la página directamente.

Si quieres persistir el valor del último `id_modulo` enviado, puedes hacerlo en una variable de sesión:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['id_modulo'])) {
  $id_modulo = $_POST['id_modulo'];
  $_SESSION['id_modulo'] = $_POST['id_modulo'];
} else if (isset($_SESSION['id_modulo'])) {
  $id_modulo = $_SESSION['id_modulo'];
} else {
  $id_modulo = 'todos';
}
```

Igual me extraña que si guardas el `id_modulo` seleccionado por primera vez en un input hidden, no lo esté enviando en la segunda petición.

Comment: Buenas tardes, antes que todo gracias por contestar prontamente, voy a probar este codigo y te comento.

Comment: No da la solucion que quiero porque si por ejemplo de la pagina inicial el valor de id_modulo es 3 y al acceder al formulario se equivoca de usuario o contraseña entonces se recarga la pagina pero con id_modulo = todos y lo que quiero es que se mantenga el valor anterior de id_modulo

Comment: Y cuando la persona recién ingresa, cómo sabes que el módulo es 3?

Comment: Proque desde la pagina anterior el selecciona el modulo al que quiere acceder

Comment: Pero... dices que el formulario donde elige módulo y el formulario donde envía usuario y contraseña son distintos?

Comment: Si, la pagina principal es donde estan todos los modulos, el usuario antes de loguearse escoge uno, de hay pasa a la pagina de logueo y guardo el valor de id_modulo en un campo oculto

Comment: Podrías poner el formulario en tu pregunta. Si guardas el id del módulo al renderear el segundo paso, entonces sí debiera enviarse la variable por post

Comment: Cuando voy a la consola de Firefox si esta la variable lo que no entiendo es porque no queda guardada, puedo enviarte una imagen? porque no se como poner el formulario, no me salen todas las etiquetas cuando guardo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el ultimo codigo con sesion funciono a la perfeccion, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Te sugiero que marques la pregunta como respondida. Primero, para que otra persona que tenga la misma duda pueda guiarse por lo que iteramos aquí, y segundo para que no aparezca en el feed de "preguntas sin responder" que muchos usamos para priorizar las que más necesitan atención